# Проблема с выводом рекорда C#

Tags: c#

Суть в том, что у меня есть игровое приложение. Есть текстовый файл в котором хранятся рекорды

На первом изображении как загружаются рекорды , а на втором - как выглядит рекорд в текстовом файле

Вот не знаю как нормально загрузить рекорды.

Сама функция:

```
     // Загрузка рекордов из файла
    private void loadPlayerDataButtom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (File.Exists(dataFilePath))
        {
            string[] data = File.ReadAllLines(dataFilePath);

            foreach (string dataItem in data)
            {
                ListViewItem newListViewItem = new ListViewItem(dataItem);
                newListViewItem.SubItems.Add(dataItem);
                newListViewItem.SubItems.Add(dataItem);
                recordsDataListView.Items.Add(newListViewItem);
            }

            if (clearPlayerDataButton.Enabled == false)
            {
                clearPlayerDataButton.Enabled = true;
            }

            MessageBox.Show(this, "Данные успешно загружены.", "Информация", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, "Файл не найден!", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что Вас не устраивает, и какой результат желателен?

Comment: @igor Нужно что бы в каждый столбец записывались свои значения, а именно в столбце имя - только имя, в столбце счёт - счёт и в столбце время только время

Comment: Лучше для таких вещей использовать SQLite.

Comment: @Sppevg, а Вы не думали не в `txt` сохранять, а, например, `xml`? Мне кажется, так удобней было бы. Или именно `txt` нужен?

Comment: @Sv__t Даже и не думал об этом. Сразу что-то в txt записывать захотелось

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот попробуйте:

```
// Загрузка рекордов из файла
private void loadPlayerDataButtom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (File.Exists(dataFilePath))
    {
        string[] data = File.ReadAllLines(dataFilePath);

        var items = new List<string>();

        for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            string dataItem = data[i];
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataItem))
            {
                items.Add(dataItem);
                if (i < data.Length - 1)
                    continue;
            }
            if (items.Count != 3)
                continue;

            var newListViewItem = new ListViewItem(items[0]);
            newListViewItem.SubItems.Add(items[1]);
            newListViewItem.SubItems.Add(items[2]);
            recordsDataListView.Items.Add(newListViewItem);
            items.Clear();
        }

        if (clearPlayerDataButton.Enabled == false)
        {
            clearPlayerDataButton.Enabled = true;
        }

        MessageBox.Show(this, "Данные успешно загружены.", "Информация", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this, "Файл не найден!", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Загружает не все данные. Поле имя пропускает и начинает запись со счёта. В счёт записывает имя, а в время - счёт

Comment: @Sppevg поправил

Comment: @Scrim Всё равно что-то не проходит. Так же не все данные загружает Такая же ошибка http://prntscr.com/fexuyf

Comment: @Sppevg можете прислать исходники?

Comment: Если только вам на почту лично.

Comment: Сейчас пришлю исходник.

Comment: @jon smith С этим я вообще не знаком

Comment: отправил уже. Можете просмотреть

Comment: Ничего не пришло

Comment: с mail.ru не удалось отправить, пересылаю с gmail

Comment: а сейчас пришло с gmail должно?

Comment: Да, пришло, сейчас посмотрю.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.

Comment: Поправил ответ. Но все это конечно костыли, лучше разберитесь как работать с бд.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Буду разбираться

Answer (score 5):

Позвольте, я покажу другой подход.

Для начала, создадим модель данных:

```
public class Record
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
}
```

Для работы с набором записей объявляем коллекцию (можно любой другой подходящий тип - например, `BindingList`):

```
List<Record> records; // поле формы
```

Заполним её тестовыми данными (ниже показано чтение из файла):

```
records = new List<Record>
{
    new Record { Name="Test",  Score=1200, Time=new TimeSpan(0,0,12) },
    new Record { Name="Test1", Score=1600, Time=new TimeSpan(0,0,8)  },
    new Record { Name="Test2", Score=1800, Time=new TimeSpan(0,0,6)  }
};
```

---

Теперь с коллекцией можно удобно работать.

Добавление записи:

```
records.Add(new Record { Name="test3", Score=2000, Time=new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10) });
```

Поиск:

```
var maxScore = records.Max(r => r.Score); // наибольший счёт
var maxRecord = records.Find(r => r.Score == maxScore); // запись с наибольшим счётом
```

Удаление записи:

```
records.Remove(maxRecord);
```

И т. п.

---

Для сохранения в файл и чтения оттуда проще всего использовать сериализацию. Например, в JSON. Возьмём для этого популярную библиотеку JSON.NET (подключите через nuget).

```
using Newtonsoft.Json; // открываем пространство имён
```

Сохранение делается несолькими строками кода:

```
// Настраиваем вывод с отступами для читаемости
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(records, settings);
File.WriteAllText("test.json", json);
```

Так будет выглядеть файл:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Test",
    "Score": 1200,
    "Time": "00:00:12"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Test1",
    "Score": 1600,
    "Time": "00:00:08"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Test2",
    "Score": 1800,
    "Time": "00:00:06"
  }
]
```

Десериализуются данные тоже элементарно:

```
var text = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
records = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Record>>(text);
```

---

А для отображения следует использовать привязку данных:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = records;
```

Я взял `DataGridView`, так как он больше подходит для показа табличных данных.

Напоследок, поменяем заголовки грида:

```
dataGridView.Columns["Name"].HeaderText = "Имя";
dataGridView.Columns["Score"].HeaderText = "Счёт";
dataGridView.Columns["Time"].HeaderText = "Время";
```